# iOS photo permissions to ask for second time

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

I am currently using alasset which asks for permission for first time. If want to pop permission second time or every time when user has blocked it, how it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dialog isn't controlled by the app, so no API for that.

You can reset things as a user in the settings app (IIRC) but no programmatic way.

---

To get the current authorization status:

```
[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];

(+ (ALAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus)
```

---

Also, methods to get assets taking access error blocks, e.g.:

```
- (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL
        resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock
       failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. please can you tell me how to handle just to prompt  user that he/she blocked the access.

Comment: added.. you just check the authorizationStatus and if it is `ALAuthorizationStatusDenied` show a `UIAlertView`

Comment: [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] only works on iOS6 and higher. An approach that works under iOS5 and iOS 6 is to call enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock: of AssetsLibrary. If the failureblock returns ALAssetsLibraryAccessUserDeniedError or ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError the user has not granted access to the Photo-Library/Location Services.

Comment: I mentioned that the that many method take a failureblock BUT unless otherwise noted I think it is ok to assume the current os

Answer (score 4):

there is no way to show the permission prompt the second time.

The best way to handle the permission prompt is that you should explain to the user before triggering the permission prompt (read: call method in the AssetsLibrary framework). If the user still click on "Don't Allow", then you should tell the user how can he/she grant the permission via the Settings app as you cannot invoke the prompt for the second time.