# Reset permissions for ALAssetsLibrary in the simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I have an `iOS` app which needs to ask the user for permissions to access their photos. I am trying to enhance the user experience by displaying a prompt and explanation to the user the first time the app requests iOS for permission.

I can use `[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]` to get the current status (my app is targeting > `iOS 6.0` only). I'm trying test the `ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` case, but I've already granted my app access. According to another SO question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969544/ios-photo-permissions-to-ask-for-second-time), the device cannot reset the permissions (they are either on or off, even if the app is deleted and reinstalled).

But I am wondering if this can be done in the simulator. **Can I reset the photo access permissions in the simulator?** There don't seem to be any google question/answers about this? Simply deleting and reinstalling the app in the simulator does not work.

Are there any under-the-hood files we can reset? - seeing how we have access to the simulators file system, unlike the devices.

Any thoughts would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try "Reset Content and Settings ..." from the iOS Simulator menu? (But note that this removes all apps from the simulator and resets everything in the simulator!)

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. the authorizationStatus still comes back as `ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 9):

In iOS 7 you can reset the privacy warnings in the Simulator in the same way as on the device:

```
 General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [iOS 6.0 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html):

> No privacy alerts are displayed in iOS Simulator for apps that access
>   Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders.

So you cannot test the prompt asking for access to photos on the Simulator at all, you have to test it on the device. On the device you can reset the privacy settings in the "Settings" app (General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy).